# How do I put some chars into a string object allocated previously?

Tags: c++

Why can't I strcpy some chars to a "string" object variable allocated as a part of structure?

```
struct person
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int age;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    person * pupil = new person;
    char temp[] = "Test";
    strcpy(pupil->firstname, temp); // THIS IS INVALID, WHY?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Because `std::string` is not a simple C-style string, it's a class. Use assignment to make a copy.

Comment: You might like to forget that you've ever heard of `strcpy` and similar functions, and instead learn how to use C++ strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::strings` are not plain character arrays, do they cannot be used directly as a target with `strncpy`.

As for your code, you can simply assign a string literal to an existing `string` object such as a data member of a `person` object. The string will create an internal copy based on the literal. For example,

```
person pupil;
pupil.firstname = "Test";

std::cout << pupil.firstname << std::endl; // prints "Test"
```

Note there is no need to allocate a `person` object dynamically. There is also no need for the temporary `char` array.

Note that, in your case, you can also *initialize* the members using a brace enclosed initializer list:

```
person pupil = { "John", "Doe", 42, 'F' };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `pupil->firstname` is not a character pointer.

Why not read up on std:string and compare it to the manual page for strcpy

Answer (score 0):

Because `strcpy` works with C-style strings (char buffers), and a `std::string` is not a C-style string.

You can simply do this instead:

```
pupil->firstname = temp;
```

Or, avoid the `temp` altogether:

```
pupil->firstname = "Test";
```

Even better, have your `person`'s constructor actually construct a fully-formed object:

```
struct person
{
    person ()
    : 
      firstname ("Test")
    {
    }

    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int age;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    person * pupil = new person;
}
```